# Scala write collection of objects to HttpResponse

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm scala beginner and for now I'm trying to build a basic play/slick app (sort of user database).

It seems I've been able to build up all the stuff but data transferring to the front-end.

Here is what I have:

**UserDAO.scala**

```
class UserDao @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends BaseDao {
  import driver.api._

  def entities = TableQuery[UsersTable]

  def all(): Future[Seq[User]] = {
    db.run(entities.result)
  }

  class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends BaseTable(tag, "USER") {
    def email = column[String]("email")
    def password = column[String]("password")
    def * = (id, email, password) <> (User.tupled, User.unapply)
  }
}
```

**Application.scala**

```
Application @Inject()(userDAO: UserDao) extends Controller {
  def users = Action.async {
    val userList = userDAO.all()
    userList
      .map { list => Ok(list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem : UserDto))) }
      .recover { case _ => InternalServerError }
  }
}
```

**UserDTO.scala**

```
case class UserDto(id: Long, login: String)

object UserDto {
  implicit val userWriter = Json.writes[UserDto]

  implicit def from(user: User): UserDto = UserDto(user.id, user.login)
}
```

What I don't understand is why compiler complains about `.map { list => Ok(list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem : UserDto))) }` in Application.scala. It seems that I provided everything required for conversion to `json`. Could please, anybody, show what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `Json.toJson(list)`.  You seem to be trying to return a list of JSON objects rather than a json array.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Ok(list.map(elem => Json.toJson(elem : UserDto)))` with `Json.toJson(list: Seq[UserDto])`

```
Application @Inject()(userDAO: UserDao) extends Controller {
  def users = Action.async {
    val userList = userDAO.all()
    userList
      .map { list => Ok(Json.toJson(list: Seq[UserDto])) }
      .recover { case _ => InternalServerError }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, pamu! Just wondering, can we use implicit conversion to eliminate explicit `from` function usage?

Comment: @mr.nothing i don't think the `implicit` def will be automatically picked up in this case

Comment: @mr.nothing just added it to be safe.

Comment: @mr.nothing Yes .. just check it ... implicit will be picked up

Comment: @mr.nothing The `implicit` will be picked up

Comment: @mr.nothing Yes !!! we use implicit conversion to eliminate explicit from function usage